# forming URL in JSP facing issue due to Single Quote and Double Quote

Tags: javascript, jsp

**Below Is the actual url and I need to pass one dynamic parameter in URl after "refresh=true"**

**I am facing difficulties while concating**.

```
<%! String newTime=null; %>
<%
newTime = df1.format(stopTime.getTime()); 
%>
```

**above newTime variable I want to pass as request parameter.**

```
<a href="javascript:window.location('<c:url value="/protected/mypage/newmypage.jsp?refresh=true" />')" onclick="return theFunction();">update</a>
```

Comment: paramname=<%=newTime;%>

Comment: Thanks for reply , I know how to add request param.my issue is different ,I am facing issue while concating this param.if you can concate this additional param correctly then I will get my answer.

Comment: how did you tried it to pass? try this `value="/protected/mypage/newmypage.jsp?refresh=true&paramname=<%=newTime;%>"`

Comment: its not working..<%=newTime;%> going as paraname value